# Java parameter passing in bst implementaion

Tags: java, parameter-passing, binary-search-tree

I am returning to Java after a long time with C and have been caught up on a simple concept.  I started writing a basic BST implementation to get my bearings back, and thought I understood Java's pass-by-value parameter passing (yes I understand that even object references are passed by value, a very common misunderstanding).

I implement the add functionality recursively as shown in the code below, however I found that if I do not actually return the node values, it does not work.  I have commented out the lines that don't work and replaced them with the lines that do work for comparison.

My thought was that because a copy of the reference to the actual root node is being passed to the add function, the changes to done in each function call are done on the actual object in memory, so if I added a node to the left or right branch, it should be retained.

I feel very embarrassed because I know I must be missing something really simple here, but reading about java argument passing seems makes me wonder why I am wrong.  Thanks for the help.

```
public class BinaryTree {

    TreeNode root;

    public BinaryTree(){
        root = null;
    }

    void add(int item){
        root = add(root,item);
        //add(root,item);
    }

    //public void TreeNode add(TreeNode node, int item){
    public TreeNode add(TreeNode node, int item){
        if(node == null){
            node = new TreeNode(item);
        } else if(item <= node.getItem()){
            node.setLeft(add(node.getLeft(),item));
            //add(node.getLeft(),item);
        } else if(item > node.getItem()){
            node.setRight(add(node.getRight(),item));
            //add(node.getRight(),item);
        } 
        return node;
        //return;
    }
    static void printTree(BinaryTree tree){
        printTree(tree.root);
    }
    static void printTree(TreeNode node){
        if(node == null){
            System.out.println("Tree Empty");
            return;
        }
        if(node.getLeft() != null)
            printTree(node.getLeft());
        if(node.getRight() != null){
            System.out.print(node.getItem()+ ", ");
            printTree(node.getRight());
        } else {
            System.out.print(node.getItem()+ ", ");
        }
        return;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        BinaryTree tree1 = new BinaryTree();
        tree1.add(10);
        tree1.add(3);
        tree1.add(5);
        printTree(tree1);
    }
}`
```

Comment: If your root is null then you need to set it to something. If you pass null to add(node, item) you create a new node, but it isn't referenced anywhere outside of the function until you return it and do something with it.

Comment: Of course!  Thanks I had tunnel vision!

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your `void add` method, you're setting the root equal to the result of `TreeNode add` so you have to return something or else the root will be null. For example, let's add the first element to the BST. After running the `TreeNode add` method, something has to be returned, because this will eventually be assigned to `root` in your `void add` method. Here's a rundown with what will happen if you don't return anything.

```
void add(10) gets executed
root = add(root, 10)
TreeNode add(root, 10) gets executed
if(node == null) evaluates to true
node = new TreeNode(10); // this is where java being pass by value matters
```

You think that root is actually changing to a new TreeNode object with its item value as 10. However, this is not happening. Rather whenever a method that takes in parameters is called, pointers are made that point to the objects in these parameters. So calling `TreeNode add(root, 10)` creates a pointer to `root`. This pointer is called `node`, so when you're changing `node` in the last line here, it's changing what the pointer `node` points to, leaving `root` untouched. If you don't return `node`, then you're doing nothing with this reference to the new TreeNode object you just created so it ends up being lost in Java's garbage collection.

Comment: I commented out the lines that didn't work, so in my void add method I actually was using just the call add(root,item) with no assignment.  But your answer cleared up the problem, I was not doing anything with my newly created node in the null root case.  Thanks!!